# How to change the pitch of sound in audiotrack?

Tags: android, audiorecord, audiotrack

I have a project in which the users voice should get repeated just like an echo or Talking tom app.I have used AudioRecorder and Audiotrack features,but my problem is I am not able to vary the pitch of sound I have referred http://androidsourcecode.blogspot.in/2013/07/android-audio-demo-audiotrack.html this and http://android-er.blogspot.in/2012/06/implement-voice-changer-by-changing.html this tutorials ...
I have changed the frequency in Audiotrack 7000hz through this sound varies but after making a long sentence it replicates the cutted sound not the entire sentence....

I want monster like repeated sound...
I am newbie in Android
Please Help me ..
I am stuck since long time 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
SoundPool sp = new SoundPool(1, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,0);
        //explosion = sp.load(this, R.raw.hh,0);
        int explosion = sp.load(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/test.amr",0);
        sp.play(explosion, 1,1,0,0,2f);
```

Comment: How about pointing out what about this code is affecting the pitch.

Comment: While this may answer the question it’s always a good idea to put some text in your answer to explain what you're doing. Read [how to write a good answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This soundpool  will be change voice. you will be use to change 2f,2.1,2.2,. etc using to change voice with your recorded voice. sp.play(explosion, 1,1,0,0,2f);